# How to paste text before the cursor in vim when the key p is pressed?

Tags: vim

In vim, when I press `p`, text was pasted to after the cursor? How can I change this to paste the text before the cursor?

My problem comes from this situation: there are hundreds of lines propositions in a text file. I have to check manually if they are right. If a certain line is right, I should put a mark `*` before that line, so I hope I can paste text before the cursor.

Comment: Have you used the help? `:help p`; your desired command is just four lines below that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<kbd>P</kbd>

Note that `P` is capitalized.

Typing `:help p` gives more info about both `p` and `P`.

Answer (score 4):

Try capital P.

Lowercase <kbd>p</kbd> puts after the cursor.

Capital <kbd>P</kbd> puts before the cursor.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative way that *I* think fits  your usecase better:

```
I*<esc>   insert a * at the beginning of the line
j         move to next line
.         repeat last edit if the line is "right"
```

After that, your work id going to look like `jjjj.j.jjj.jjj.j.j.jjjjjjj.jj.`. You are free to use the `<down>` key, if you like it better.

Also, but that might be cheating, if the "right" lines exhibit some sort of pattern the `:global` command would help:

```
:%g/pattern/norm I*
```